# How to render v-for from particular index

Tags: vue.js

I want to loop in v-for from suppose from number 5 to 10 . 
The loop want to be started at 5 and end at 10.

I have tried this

```
<div v-for="n in 10" v-if="n>=5"></div>
```

But I want more effective way of doing the loop  . Does anyone knows how to do so that loop starts at 5 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its possible for your example:

```
<div v-for="i in range(5, 10)">
... some code here
</div>
```

and mount range function:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods:{
    range : function (start, end) {
      return Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx)
   }
  }
});
```

and sample in [jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/ft86rp1r/9/).

If want know more than this [github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3641) can help you.

Comment: its so funny that this is not build into vue

Comment: @Adam are kidding me?

Comment: not kidding you, I really find it funny that this is not build in vue by default.

Comment: You must make sure youre syntax is OK.

Comment: I have the feeling that we talk past each other. I think you post is great and I up voted it. Its all good! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Also try this simple approach:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {
    items: [
      '1',
      '2',
      '3',
      '4',
      '5',
      '6',
      '7',
      '8',
      '9',
      '10'
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    sliceItems: function (start, end) {
      return this.items.slice(start, end);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in sliceItems(5,10)" >{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple alternative is to just use basic `+`/`-`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    start: 5,
    end: 10
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="i in end-start" >{{ i+start }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you really need to use `{{ i }}` a lot of times and is bothered by adding start, you can use a little trick:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    start: 5,
    end: 10
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <template v-for="curr in end-start" >
      <li v-for="i in [curr+start]">
        {{ i }}{{ i }}{{ i }}{{ i }}{{ i }}{{ i }}{{ i }}{{ i }}{{ i }}
      </li>
    </template>
  </ul>
</div>
```