# How to generate range by v-for in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ecmascript-6, range

Like this:

```
range(3, 5) -> [3, 4]
range(5, 10) -> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I know we can generate `range(1, x)` by `v-for`, so I did a try like this:

```
// I want to generate the number of range(5, 10), so I can set (10 - 5) on `v-for`
// and plus (5 - 1) to the result to get the number I want. 
<span v-for="number in 5">
    The number is {{ number + 4 }}.
</span>
```

It works nice... but it's hard to understand.

Comment: there is not a function like range() in js all you have to do is to make a function which returns an array of required elements or range

Comment: Did you try (number, index) to do the purpose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render v-for from particular index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715339/how-to-render-v-for-from-particular-index)

Comment: @Cyrbuzz, I think you can find all information about how `v-for` works in documentation - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range. Vue.js have a great documentation that covers a lot of topics about vue

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create the range function yourself.

```
export default {
  methods: {
    range = (start, end) => {
      if (!end) {
        end = start
        start = 0
      }
      start -= 1
      end -= 1
      let arr = []
      while (start++ !== end) {
        arr.push(start)
      }
      return arr
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code such that others can learn from it